# Difference between using getConnection() and using pool directly in node.js with node-mysql module?

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

The documentation states that you can either use the pool directly with:

```
pool.query();
```

or get a connection manually and then run a query:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // Use the connection
  connection.query( 'SELECT something FROM sometable', function(err, rows) {
    // And done with the connection.
    connection.release();

    // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
  });
});
```

The second option is a lot of code that has to be repeated every time you need to run a query. Is it safe to just use the pool directly? Does `pool.query()` release the connection back into the pool when it's done?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Question kindly answered by developer on github:
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/857#issuecomment-47382419

> **Is it safe to just use the pool directly?**
>
> Yes, as long as you are doing single statement queries. The only
>   reason you couldn't use that in your example above is because you are
>   making multiple queries that need to be done in sequential order on
>   the same connection. Calling pool.query() may be different connections
>   each time, so things like FOUND_ROWS() will not work as you intended
>   if the connection is not the same as the one that did the
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS query. Using the long method allows you to hold
>   onto the same connection for all your queries.
>
> **Does pool.query() release the connection back into the pool when it's**
>   **done?**
>
> Yes

Comment: According to this answer and the [documents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections), `pool.query()` is equivalant to getting a connection from the pool, executing a query with it, and then releasing it, but as I tested these two methods for executing a simple `SELECT` query, there was a considerable exec time difference between them, 500 ms in my case. Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Galiold, I notice the same performance hit in getting a pool connection. Seems to take a minimum of 20ms, sometimes much more for me.